# How to get data Mysql group by with condition counter

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, counter

Mysql group by counter (how many conditions)

Hi, every one

I want to;

- question_id 1 and answer 2
- question_id 2 and answer 2
- question_id 3 and ve answer 2
- question_id 4 and ve answer 2
- question_id 5 and ve answer 2

I would like to group by group by object_id and see what object_id is matched by how many conditions in a field called match_ number.

Like a result;

```
Object_id   Eşleşme_sayısı
    1             3
    2             5
```

Screen a table ;

[image: table screen]

Table sql codes;

```
CREATE TABLE `object_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `object_answers_question_id_foreign` (`question_id`),
  KEY `object_answers_object_id_foreign` (`object_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `object_answers_object_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) REFERENCES `object` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `object_answers_question_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `object_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `object_answers_question_id_foreign` (`question_id`),
  KEY `object_answers_object_id_foreign` (`object_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `object_answers_object_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) REFERENCES `object` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `object_answers_question_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: image  => https://i.hizliresim.com/dvmDR7.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question

Comment: To post content of a table (which is a good thing in an SQL question) use `INSERT INTO` statements but **no** images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL's ability to cast Boolean expressions into `0` or `1` in numeric context. Therefore you can indirectly sum a Boolean expression.

```
SELECT obejct_id,
       sum(question_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
           AND answer = 2) "Eşleşme_sayısı"
       FROM object_answers
       GROUP BY object_id;
```